# Vue/Apollo/graphql client cannot read 'watchQuery' error

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I'm trying to consume a remote GraphQL API from Vue using the `apollo-client` library and having trouble. I get:

`Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'watchQuery' of undefined"`

Code is on github at https://github.com/odessa-paige-turner/vue-apollo-graphql

Have you used Apollo? What has been your experience with it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the plugin (`vue add apollo`) rather than the manual installation. Then I used the [Usage in Vue Components](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-option/usage.html#apollo-options) guide to do the rest.